# Shortening the answering time?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the fonction $(5,5)\ni w\mapsto \lambda(w,k)$ for $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ where $\lambda(w,k)$ is defined below on the penultimate line. The answering time looks infinite and I was not even able to draw the curve  of $w\mapsto A11[w,k]$. I suspect that my code could be improved, and I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Here is the code:

```js
setTimeout(function (
F[w_, k_, t_] = 
 1/(6 \[Pi])
   Exp[I w Log[(1 + 1/3 Exp[I t])/(
     1 - 1/3 Exp[I t])]]  Exp[-6 I k Exp[-I t]]/
  Sqrt[ 1 - 1/9 Exp[2 I t]]  Exp[I t]

R[w_, k_] = 
 Integrate[F[w, k, t], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Assumptions -> {w \[Element] Reals, k > 0}]

A11[w_, k_] = 
 1/(1 + Exp[-2 \[Pi] w ]) + 
  Exp[-\[Pi] w]/(1 + Exp[-2 \[Pi] w ]) Im[R[w, k]]

B1[w_, k_] = 
 Integrate[
  Exp[s w - k Tan[s]] (2 Sinh[s w - k  Tan[s]])/Sin[s], {s, 
   0, \[Pi]/2}, Assumptions -> {w \[Element] Reals, k > 0}]

B3[w_, k_] = 
 Integrate[2 (Sinh[s w - k Tanh[s]])^2/Sinh[s] , {s, 0, \[Pi]/2}]

B4[w_, k_] = 
 Integrate[Cos[2 (s w - k Tanh[s])]/Sinh[s] , {s, \[Pi]/2, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {w \[Element] Reals, k > 0}]

A12[w_, k_] = 
 Exp[-\[Pi]  w]/(
  2 \[Pi]) (B1[w, k] - Log[Tanh[\[Pi]/4]] + B3[w, k] + B4[w, k])

\[Lambda][w_, k_] = 
 1/2 (A11[w, k] + 
    Sqrt[(A11[w, k])^2 (1 + Exp[-2 \[Pi]  w]) + 4 (A12[w, k])^2])


) { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: What ranges do you make your plots in? Can you redefine your code to work with `NIntegrate`?

Comment: Do not include the option `Assumptions` more than once. Either combine the assumptions in a list: `Assumptions -> {w \[Element] Reals, k > 0}`; or as a logical combination: `Assumptions -> w \[Element] Reals && k > 0`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thanks for correcting this.

Comment: This is not Mathematica code.

Answer (score 3):

One way to have faster plotting is:

1. To use `NIntegrate` in `B1` with smaller precision and accuracy goals
2. Run `B1` over a list of values for `w` and/or `k`

```
Clear[B1];
B1[w_, k_] := 
  Integrate[
    Exp[s w - k Tan[s]] (2 Sinh[s w - k Tan[s]])/Sin[s], {s, 
     0, \[Pi]/2}, Assumptions -> w \[Element] Reals, 
    Assumptions -> k > 0] /; k > 0;
B1[w_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    Exp[s w - k Tan[s]] (2 Sinh[s w - k Tan[s]])/Sin[s], {s, 
     0, \[Pi]/2}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 3] /; k > 0;

AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{wPoints = Range[100], kPoints = Range[100]},
  lsPoints = 
    Flatten[Table[{w, k, B1[w, k]}, {w, wPoints}, {k, kPoints}], 1];
  ]
 ]

ListPlot3D[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], Log[#[[3]]]} &, lsPoints], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. In fact, the function $B1$ is part of a subsequent formula defining another function $F$: something like $F[w_,k_]=B1[w,k]+...$ and I have trouble to use NIntegrate in that situation.

Comment: @Beziin Please, give a fuller description and/or code in your post then!

Comment: I did that, thanks for your follow-up.